# How to get csp violation from console error in puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, content-security-policy

I am trying to collect all console errors in the browser using Puppeteer with nodeJS, I couldn't find any event for content-security-policy violation error in puppeteer documents.

There are events in puppeteer for error, pageerror, requestfailed, These events don't get triggered for content-security-policy violation error. Is there any event for getting content-security-polic violations?

Something like this,

```
page.on('csperror(dummy-text)', csperror=> {
       console.log('pageerror occurred: ', csperror);
     })
```

Comment: The [SecurityPolicyViolationEvent](https://csplite.com/csp30/#SecurityPolicyViolationEvent) interface is provided since CSP2. Verify `if ('SecurityPolicyViolationEvent' in window) {...}` and then you can use `window.addEventListener('securitypolicyviolation', ... );` to add event listener.